# Assertion error in unit test

Tags: python

I am working on a python program to find all numbers in a range which are perfect squares and sum of all digits in the number is less than 10

My test case shows an assertion error

```
AssertionError: None != [1, 4, 9, 16]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Why is this happening

```
def perfSq(l,u):
    a=[]
    for x in range(l,u+1):
        if (int(x**0.5))**2==x and sum(list(map(int,str(x))))<10:
            a.append(x)
    print a


import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    def testPerfSq(self):
        self.assertEqual(perfSq(1,20) , [1,4,9,16] ) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is there anything wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

`perfSq` returns `None`. You are comparing `None` to `[1, 4, 9, 16]`

Change

```
def perfSq(l,u):
    a=[]
    for x in range(l,u+1):
        if (int(x**0.5))**2==x and sum(list(map(int,str(x))))<10:
            a.append(x)
    print a
```

to

```
def perfSq(l,u):
    a=[]
    for x in range(l,u+1):
        if (int(x**0.5))**2==x and sum(list(map(int,str(x))))<10:
            a.append(x)
    print a
    return a
```